# Reference varying names in JSON object C#

Tags: c#, json, variables

I have the following:

```
dynamic myJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
```

Within myJSON there will be a varying number of items that have the same name apart from a number at the end e.g.

```
string v1 = myJSON.variable1;
string v2 = myJSON.variable2;
string v3 = myJSON.variable3;
```

Sometimes there could be 3 (as above), sometimes there could be 12, at other times, only 1, or any other number.

How can I add them all to strings when I don't know how many there will be?

TIA

Comment: you could use a List; well need more info, though, like example JSON, Mapping class, ...

Comment: Do you have control or at least some say in the structure of that json?

Answer (score 2):

You might have better luck not using `dynamic`. With a `JObject` you can index into it with a string:

```
string variableName = "something";
var myJSON = JObject.Parse(data);
string v1 = myJSON[variableName + "1"];
string v2 = myJSON[variableName + "2"];
//...etc.
```

> Update

You can get the number of items with `myJSON.Count`.

This is all assuming your structure is flat and you don't need to drill into nested objects.

Comment: Good first step. Still he has to know the count of the properties at compiletime. Edit: I was pointing towards ```string v1=...``` could be replaced by a List ;)

Comment: Thanks. I've been able to sort it with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could deserilize the data into a dictionary and then iterate through the keys. e.g.

```
var data = @"{ ""variable1"":""var1"", ""variable2"":""var2"", ""variable3"":""var3"", ""variable4"":""var4"" }";
var deserializedDictionary  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(data);
foreach(var item in deserializedDictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {item.Key}, Value: {item.Value}");
}
```

Although I have assumed the value is a string in the example above, it could be any object.